# Form nonces on load balancers?

Tags: php, forms, load-balancing, nonce

We're trying to minimize bot hits to our search URL (meaning it doesn't load the form but just sends the params), and I think using a nonce in a hidden input would solve that, but our admin says the load-balanced servers may send the form nonce from one server but the form submit could be processed by another server... so I'm not sure how we could get this to work and I'm getting seemingly irrelevant/unrelated results when web-searching for this whole issue.

I worked on a few form nonce implementations years ago but they all went through the same server (one was auto-generated by CakePHP, the other I don't remember how we did it). We're using httpd with PHP 5.x on CentOS 6.x servers, and the Live servers have 1 staging server that serves requests and then 10 load balancers (not sure if that really matters, but they have a copy of the file system and code while hitting the same database).

The admin is familiar with load balancing (I've never done it) and says he may be able to implement some sort of persistence or use memcache -d or something like that (I've never tried that), but I'm not quite sure about this.

Comment: Well fundamentally there are two ways to fix it. You can either implement "sticky" sessions on your load balancer, or store the nonces somewhere that all the webservers can see them - this could be a shared session store like memcache, a database, or even just a network directory. Or both. What makes most sense will depend on your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a nonce is a good choice. The workflow could be

1. GET request for form
2. Generate a random nonce value, e.g. `bin2hex(openssl_pseudo_random_bytes(16))`
3. Store the nonce in persistent shared storage. If you're not using sessions, a simple key-value store like Redis or memcache would be appropriate.
4. Add the nonce to the response in a cookie or hidden form value.
5. Form is POSTed back to load balancer. If you used a cookie for the nonce, the load balancer could immediately reject any request missing the cookie. Otherwise the request is sent to one of the web servers.
6. PHP reads nonce from the form POST or cookie.  If it's missing, reject the request (e.g. 404).
7. Checked shared storage or session for the nonce.  If it's not found, reject the response.  If it is found, remove it from storage (so it can't be used again) and process the form submission.